# jQuery hover stuck

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I hover over an img which fades to another img and sroll off too fast, the fadeOut gets stuck and the fade stays. I've tried the .stop() as I've seen in other responses, but still won't work. Is there something else I can put instead of the .stop()?

```
<div class="grid big-square">
  <a href="#"><img id="image2" src="img/fade/creo.png">
  <img id="image1" src="img/creo.jpg"></a>
</div>

<script>
$("#image1").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).stop(true, true).fadeOut(1000);
});

$("#image2").mouseleave(function () {
    $("#image1").stop(true, true).fadeIn(500);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Create a JSFiddle? It's likely that the problem is not in these lines.

Comment: I don't see what else could be the problem, this is the only jQuery I have. I've added the code that's related. Where else do you think could be conflicting with it.? @frnhr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to remember having a similar problem when I was creating [this](http://www.luckysaddleupholstery.com/page/designs/) website.

The solution is to use a combination of `.hover()` and `.stop()` to ensure that only one animation is running at a time, which I think you have. Also ensure that the mouseover image is on top of the other image, and just fade that one in and out. The image fading out gets 'stuck' because at some opacity the `.mouseleave()` stops firing and the `.mouseenter()` starts firing on the other image.

Something like:

```
$$ = $("#image1");
$$.hover(function () {
    $$.stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 1000);
}, function () {
    $$.stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 1000);
});
```

`#image1` must be above `#image2` for this to work, `#image1` fades out to 'reveal' `#image2` behind it. The code uses `.animate()` rather than `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` but the effect is the same.

**Edit-** to fade in another div after the end of the fadeoout animation use the complete call back of the animate function.

Something like:

```
$$ = $("#image1");
$$.hover(function () {
    $$.stop().animate({
        opacity: 0
    }, 1000);
}, function () {
    $$.stop().animate({
        opacity: 1
    }, 1000, function() {
        $("#finalDiv").animate({ opacity: 1, 500 });
    });
});
```

`#finalDiv` needs to be after the 2 `<img />s` in your html to appear above them.

Comment: Awesome it worked, but for some reason #image2 still needs to be before #image1. Another question: What if I wanted to fade another separate div on top of the image once faded? @Henry Florence

Comment: putting `#image1` after `#image2` ensures it will be drawn on top of it. To fade in another element afterwards I guess, use the callback function of `.animate()` as used in the other answer, see edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're trying to accomplish this but I do know how it should be done.
Try this http://jsfiddle.net/xy5dj/

Make sure to listen for both events on the same element (preferably a wrapper element).
Take note that fadeOut actually removes the element from the rendered content (display: none) making sure that the mouse events won't fire on that element.

Side note:
A dirty trick that I used once (if you have to do this then you're doing something wrong) is to clear the style of the element after animation using the callback ability of the animate function i.e.

```
$('el').animate({opacity:0}, 500, function(){$(this).attr('style', '')});
```

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dqf7s/)</kbd>

You should use the animation/transition in form:

```
.fadeTo( duration, opacity, complete )
```

where `complete` is callback function.