# Background image on hover stuck when changing pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some background images appearing on hover on my [homepage](http://arijoseph.com), but when I click on a link, the background image persists onto the next page (presumably because there's some AJAX conflict that is not killing the hover function).

I created a [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/bKQENr) to troubleshoot what was happening, and tried to add a `mouseleave` function as a kill for the image but I'm still having the same issue.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#ado').hover(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("https://files.cargocollective.com/c169426/drone_footage.gif")');
  }, function() {
    $('body').css('background', '');
  });

  $("#ado").mouseleave(function() {
    $("#ado").css("background-image", "");
  });

  $('#workspace').hover(function() {
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url("https://files.cargocollective.com/c169426/ezgif.com-optimize.gif")');
  }, function() {
    $('body').css('background', '');
  });
});
```

I read through [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19897437/jquery-hover-stuck) which was similar but still wasn't having much luck getting to the bottom of it.

Comment: Your homepage doesn't have that issue when I go to look at it. What browser are you viewing it with? I tried Chrome and Firefox

Comment: not only mouseleave, you have to remove background on click also, better u handle the background with add/remove classes in body

Comment: @binderbound I've tried Chrome and Safari with the same problem.